# Does SharePoint online support Translation management library?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does SharePoint online support Translation management library?
If so - where can find the library?

Answer (score 2):

No.

> In Microsoft Office 365 for professionals and small businesses, SharePoint Online does not support the following feature, which is commonly included in on-premises SharePoint 2010 installations:

```
FEATURE TITLE                   FEATURE ID                              FEATURE NAME
Translation Management Library  29d85c25-170c-4df9-a641-12db0b9d4130    TransMgmtLib
```

Reference: [Why do I receive an error when I try to create a new SharePoint Online site based on a site template created in SharePoint Foundation or SharePoint Server?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/why-do-i-receive-an-error-when-i-try-to-create-a-new-sharepoint-online-site-based-on-a-site-template-created-in-sharepoint-foundation-or-sharepoint-server-HA102737458.aspx)